# Isolate scope change from Angular 1.1 to 1.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular N00b here, I'm having some with a isolate scope directives. I created a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1hf5hyh9/3/) to show the issue, but the strange part is that it seems to be working as intended in Angular v1.1, however in 1.2+ it doesn't work.

Essentially, I'm trying to create isolate scope directives, each of which has html within the directive's content itself. You'll see in the ng-show attribute I'm trying to call the isActive method on the directives with isolated scope, however that method is never fired for angular 1.2+

I'm sure I have the isolate scope stuff configured incorrectly, still trying to wrap my head around it.

Thanks!

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('stage', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: ['$scope', '$sectionService', function ($scope, $sectionService) {

            // doesn't do much yet

        }],
    };
});

app.directive('section', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            sectionIndex: '=section'
        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$sectionService', function ($scope, $sectionService) {

            $scope.isActive = function () {
                console.log("is active", $sectionService.activeSection, $scope.sectionIndex);
                return $sectionService.activeSection == $scope.sectionIndex;
            };

        }],
    };
});

app.factory('$sectionService', function () {
    return {
        activeSection: 0
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div stage>
    <div section='0' ng-show='isActive()'>This is my first section</div>
    <div section='1' ng-show='isActive()'>This is my second section</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Update: Wow sorry guys, I included the wrong Fiddle. That one should work.

Comment: Your jsfiddle does not contain code snippet above. Is that intended?

Comment: can't 2-way bind to a string as shown in uestion. Demo makes no sense when compared to question, it doesn't even have a driective in it

Answer (score 2):

Due to [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-51) breaking change in version 1.2, we can't access child's isolated scope in parent template.

Options:

1. pull out the element that requires child's isolated scope variable from parent template to child(directive).
2. If you think the element which calls `isActive()` should belong to parent, then don't create a isolate scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify the code using [element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) and showing or hiding the section when you want adding or removing the `ng-class` (css class that angular adds when it hides an element).

```
app.directive('section', function ($sectionService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            sectionIndex: '=section'
        },
        link: function(scope,element,attr){
          $sectionService.activeSection !== scope.sectionIndex ? element.addClass('ng-hide') :
 element.removeClass('ng-hide');
        }
    };
});
```

Complete code: http://plnkr.co/edit/PnQHN99TgmviLrenG5Zd